# Get current working directory relative path, not absolute

Tags: c++, c, linux

I have a directory path that has a 2nd mounted fs as part of the full path.

If I use `getcwd` it returns the absolute path of the 2nd mounted file system, not the relative path that all the app configurations need.

When I looked at the `pwd` code it showed `xgetcwd` which calls `getcwd`. It is unclear as to how:

1. `pwd` is able to return relative path using `getcwd`
2. If there is an option or command that provides the relative not absolute path.

Comment: Please check [editing-help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for formatting the question to make it more readable.

Comment: The relative path to the working directory is `.` - no need for a special function.

Comment: Do you mean the command "$ basename" ?

Comment: Do you perhaps want to `chroot` to the mounted filesystem, so that you can run some processes that only see the mounted filesystem (and that at root)? If you just want the relative path, you will have to first get the absolute path, then remove the path to the mount point. There are several approaches, but mostly it depends on whether you already know the mount point path or not; and if not, whether you know the device or not.

Answer (score 0):

First get the absolute path using:

```
char abspath[256] = "";
getcwd(abspath, 256);
```

Then get the relative path using:

```
strrchr(abspath, '/');
```